# iOS 17 Apple Music not working

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-music

[image]I updated to iOS 17 and now my Apple Music isn't working. every time I open it, it says we've run into a problem try again. ive tried restarting the app, my phone. redownloaded it, signed out and signed back in. even reset network settings. nothing seems to work. how can I fix it?